# Has Jeppesen stopped providing ARINC424 data?

Tags: arinc-424, jeppesen

As far as I am aware of, Jeppesen appears to be the main distributor of navigational data (Airports, SIDs, STARs, IAPs etc.) coded in ARINC424 format. However, I can not find on its site any product based on the aforementioned digital format. Moreover, all related links are currently broken (e.g. [ARINC 424 NavData Services](https://ww2.jeppesen.com/industry-solutions/aviation/commercial/ARINC-424.jsp), previously active based on [google cache](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:nvDYgr2CSFUJ:ww1.jeppesen.com/industry-solutions/aviation/commercial/ARINC-424.jsp+&cd=1&hl=el&ct=clnk&gl=gr)).

Could someone shed some light on this?

Comment: Try searching by "ARINC 424" instead of just one word.

Comment: @JuanJimenez thanks for your input. I have already tried different approaches regarding the possible keywords, but they yielded no results. In case you are aware of a valid relevant link, could you point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2):

Jeppesen is indeed still the main provider of ARINC 424 navigation data to OEM customers (mainly avionic suppliers). You could look at the following links on Jeppesen Web:

1. [Jeppesen NavData® and Geospatial Data](https://ww2.jeppesen.com/navigation-solutions/navdata/)
2. [Jeppesen Avionics Solutions](https://ww2.jeppesen.com/navigation-solutions/avionics-solutions/)

Other suppliers include [Lufthansa](https://www.lhsystems.com/solutions-services/flight-deck-solutions/lidonavigation/lidofms) and [Navblue](https://www.navblue.aero/)